# Is there a way to disable the tray icon for Microsoft Security Essentials?

Tags: notification-area, ms-security-essentials

It's running in the background, and seems to be working fine, but is there a way to disable its system tray icon so I don't have to see it down there unless it's detecting something going awry?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove the Microsoft Security Essentials icon](http://superuser.com/questions/105922/remove-the-microsoft-security-essentials-icon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on empty part of systray
choose "Customize Notifications"
Change the behavior of Current Item (Computer Status Protected) to "Always Hide"

This will hide the tray icon permanently.

Comment: Will that allow you to see if there are problems with MSE?

Comment: most likely, if the icon changes in case a threat is detected, the rule will no longer apply and it will become visible.

Comment: That doesn't actually *hide* the icon; it just moves it to the "overflow" area. i'm still hunting for a way to remove it completely.