# Microsoft Security Essentials: How to Disable the 'Real Time Protection Is Off' Warning?

Tags: security, anti-virus, ms-security-essentials, anti-spyware

I decided to disable the "real time protection feature" of [MSE](http://www.microsoft.com/Security_essentials). Now I have this little annoying "feature", that MSE keeps me informed that I have disabled "real time protection":

```
the little red warning symbol down in the systemtray
```

How can I disable that warning? some registry hacks? I have seen [49336](https://superuser.com/questions/49336/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-tray-icon-for-microsoft-security-essentials) (a valid option), but I only want MSE to be quiet about the 'threat of disabling real time protection'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable it by removing `msseces.exe` from HKLM's `CurrentVersion\Run` key; easily done with Autoruns. The scheduled scan is a task that runs a separate process.

(I'm being deliberately vague about how exactly to disable it to avoid corruption of the innocent.)

**Update**: Killing the process `msseces.exe` removes the tray-icon, no matter what state the program is in right now. `MsMpEng.exe` is the binary that does the real work (and it is called the same on Windows8 as well).

Comment: i don't want to disable mse (or windows-defender now on windows8), i want to not see the warning that i disabled the realtime-protection part of mse/wd.

Comment: msseces is just the desktop UI that registers the tray icon, and shows the dialogs that let you configure it. Like I said, the scheduled scan (what you have left when you disable realtime protection) is a task that runs a different executable.

Answer (score 3):

Short of removing/hiding the tray icon, you can't disable that warning. It's also a good choice for a security software to be "in-your-face" about it, as real time protection is important to most users.

Comment: well, one can discuss about the decision to 'offer disabling rtp' in the first place and THEN complaint constantly about it...

Comment: The ability to disable it is supposed to be just used temporarily (eg if you have trouble installing a program, sometimes your are sometimes asked to disable rtp to see if it is causing a conflict).

Comment: then m$ should provide a "disable for 5 minutes" button. that would be ok. but not this "yeah, you will disable it but we keep you bugged and bugged and bugged about this till you switch it backon"

Answer (score 0):

I don't have MSE installed here, so I can't test this, but when you go to the "hide inactive icons" then click customize, do you get a different entry for mse for when real-time protection is disabled, than for when it is enable or other errors?

You might be able to hide just the one you want.

Comment: well, the point is: i want to see the trayicon of all the processes which run. and i want (on reasonable events) be informed that something is wrong: i turned of mse rtp because i dont want it, so this warning is pointless. (for me :)