# Is there any way to remove tray icon?

Tags: windows-7

I was wondering if there is any way how to remove tray icon of running program such as Steam, Antivirus, etc...

I have search for answer on the Internet but I didn't find anything.

Some people ask very similar question on superuser.com
[Remove the Microsoft Security Essentials icon](https://superuser.com/questions/105922/remove-the-microsoft-security-essentials-icon)

I would like do exactly same thing but without 3rd side programs. And it would be the best if it dosen't need administrator's privileges.

So, I ask, Is there any solution how to get rid of tray icon???

Thank for every answer.

Honza.

Comment: This won't be possible without third party software

Comment: You can just hide the icon, without actually removing it... maybe that's not enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you dont want to stop them you just dont want to see them. So you can hide it. ( if you dont want them to run on start up, remove them in msconfig.

Or you can use some regedit

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local
>   Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify

And detele enteries for IconStreams

1. Source sevenforums.com

Or you can hide them, just click on costumize on try icon,

[image]

and than click on Hide icon and notification
[image]